# JQuery load function does not seem to work

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("./a.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text2</h2></div>
<button>Get External Data</button>

</body>
</html>
enter code here
```

But after clicking on button nothing happens. I also tried load("/a.txt"); Still no luck.

Tried different browsers, no success.

****Update****:

====================================================

I managed to resolve the above issue(partially) by putting the files inside the Web server.

Now I have another related issue. Button that runs Jquery only seem to work only once. That is when I change the contents of the text file and click on the Button I always see the text  of the old file. I suppose browser caches Jquery loaded data?

Comment: Did you use a web server? WHat's the contents of a.txt? Is the a.txt accessible?

Comment: ./a.txt ? should this path wrong

Comment: @praveen . No I did not initially and that was my mistake. finally I. put a a.txt and the HTMl file inside a virtual directory and it worked.
The thing is all other features of Jquery, such as animation and hide show functions do not need a web server. But obviously Jquery can only load a file if file in on the server. Is this correct?

Comment: try to change ./a.txt to '../a.txt' or '~~/a.txt'.

Comment: I changed.  ./a.txt to '../a.txt' or '~~/a.txt'

If the text file is not located on server Jquery fails to load it.

Comment: Now I have another issue. Button that runs Jquery only works once. That is when I change the contents of the text file and click on the Button I always see the contents of the old file. I suppose browser caches Jquery loaded data?

Comment: You can solve the caching issues using the answers given. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to stop your request getting cached, if you dont mind any of your ajax requests begin cached you can just add this to the start of your code.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
 cache: false
});
```

Or if you want to do it just for this request you can just add a cache clear param like

```
$("#div1").load("./a.txt?_="+Math.round(Math.random()*10000));
```

Comment: Thanks.

$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
 cache: false
}); did not work but second solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click',function(){
    $("#div1").load("../a.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text2</h2></div>
<button>Get External Data</button>

</body>
</html>
```